AMM (American Mathematical Monthly) journal bibliography style?
Could someone share the code for the bibliography style of the American Mathematical Monthly journal, published by the Mathematical Association of America (MAA)? The journal requires adherence to the following stylistic elements for citation call-outs and the formatted bibliography.

And where did you find this information?

It is just a guideline for AMM journal.

Provide a link.

https://www.editorialmanager.com/monthly/default2.aspx

Also MAA and AMS are probably not the same thing, you might want to change the title.

This refers to a bibtex style: https://maa.tandfonline.com/action/authorSubmission?show=instructions&journalCode=uamm20, linked via https://maa.org/press/periodicals/submissions-to-maa-periodicals

Where can I find the latek code for bibliography?

It is bibtex, that generates the LaTeX code for the citatation data. Most journals use bibtex for formatting the citations. See the section titled "Formatting and Templates"

Could you please type the latek code for this? I am unable to figure it out from the files.

There are templates in the Zip file. Most journals provide templates. Sorry I do not have time doing your work for you.

I've taken the liberty of editing the title and body of your query to get away from referring to the AMS and, instead, to referring to the MAA. I've also changed the search tags.

@daleif, I checked the template, there are templates for citing papers, but I don't see the latek code to add in the main file. Could you please tell me where is the code which I should add in the main file?

Using bibtex in your document should be covered in any decent introduction to latex

But The AMM journal mentions not to use Bibtex files to compile bibliography. Even though when I use it, my citations don't look exactly same as the one mentioned in the picture.

@mathisfun where does the AMM specify not to use BibTeX? The "Instructions for Authors" linked to from your comment specifically provides instructions on the BST file to use for BibTeX users. // Have you tried the template provided by the publisher? If your concern is that it provides a different output than expected, please edit your question to include your attempt at using the template, and describe how the output is different from expectations.

But with all that said: if you submit your article formatted using the TeX template that the Journal Provides, you have a perfectly good defense for any editor who wishes to complain about how the article is formatted, and it really isn't worth spending too much time on this.
